# Xamarin nfc pinned app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, nfc

I am implementing NFC into an Xamarin Forms existing app, initially  for a Zebra TC51 (android 6.0).

The app must be pinned so that users cannot access the rest of the device.

In OnCreate, within MainActivity.cs, I have the following lines:

```
NfcManager NfcManager = (NfcManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NfcService);
_nfcAdapter = NfcManager.DefaultAdapter;
```

I then use the following class to receive the tag:

```
    [Activity IntentFilter(new[] { "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" },
                 DataMimeType = MainActivity.ViewApeMimeType,
                 Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" })]
public class NfcActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DisplayHominid);
        if (Intent == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var intentType = Intent.Type ?? String.Empty;

        if (MainActivity.ViewApeMimeType.Equals(intentType))
        {
            var rawMessages = Intent.GetParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraNdefMessages);

            var tag = Intent.GetParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraTag) as Tag;
            var id = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.GetId());
            var msg = (NdefMessage)rawMessages[0];
            var tagMessage = msg.GetRecords()[0];
            var content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tagMessage.GetPayload());
            // Call another function with Tag ID and contents here
        }
    }
}
```

This code works to retrieve the tag ID and contents, but only if the app is not pinned. If the app is pinned, then the NFC service window can not be displayed, and the tag is ignored.

Can anyone suggest a way around this. I do not want to use the NFCforms NUGET package due to licecing restrictions.

TIA. Pete

Comment: What do you mean by "app is pinned"?

Comment: It is held full screen using the StartLockTask() command.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to have your application running in a kiosk mode like scenario (restricting the user to access the device) a better option could be to use [Zebra's Enterprise Home Screen](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/utilities/enterprise-home-screen.html).
In this way you can lock down the device, restricting access to notification, disabling the keyguard and more (if needed). And you can still add other apps that may be useful to the user.

In EHS' configuration you can specify that your app is launched automatically so that you're there as soon as the device is booted.

If you need to have only your app, a better solution than screen pinning maybe installing a Device Policy Controller and use the taskLockMode that has been introduced in Marshmallow [for the COSU (Corporate Owned - Single Use) devices](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html).

If still have issue you can try asking the question on [Zebra's developer forum](https://developer.zebra.com/welcome).

*Disclaimer: I work for Zebra Technologies.*

Comment: Thanks pfmaggi,
Yes, I could use Enterprise home screen, or SOTI (as we have used previously as it is cross-platform so easier to maintain).

But what I really need is to get rid of the ugly black NFC service screen which appears whenever I read a tag. That would look much better and overcome the problem.

Can you suggest how to do this?